# Can I create a Twig file of a field which can be reused in many different content types with the same Twig effect?

Tags: 8, theming

I created a Twig file for a field of a content type and made some changes in the Twig for that field. Now I want to reuse the same field  in different content type with the same Twig effect.

Is it possible if yes then how we can achieve that?

Comment: If the template is just named `field--myfield.html.twig` it will be picked up in every content type you use it unless it's not overridden by a more specific template.

Comment: Which you would know/recognize more easily with Twig debugging enabled to get template suggestions printed as HTML comments in your markup: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming/twig/debugging-twig-templates

Comment: As I checked that it is possible to use the single field in many different content types with the same twig effect unless we are using the twig naming format `field--node--myfield.html.twig` for that specific field.